# Undefined method 'column_names' when generating CSV in after_save_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, after-save

I want to generate CSV file after user creates his account, so I created `after_save` filter in `User` Model, but I'm getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
    after_save :to_csv

    def to_csv(options = {})
    require 'csv'
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << self.column_names//also tried User.column_names
        csv << self.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
    end
```

but when User is created I get error:

```
     undefined local variable or method `column_names' for #<User:0x326f778>       
     app/models/user.rb:52:in `block in to_csv'
     app/models/user.rb:50:in `to_csv'
     app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Why I'm getting this ? I'm using this railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`column_names` is a method on the class. You're calling it on the instance. If you really want `column_names` then use `self.class.column_names`.

Comment: can you suggest where is my generated file ? Also tried to generated by calling `CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w") do |csv|
`

Answer (score 3):

Try `self.attributes.keys` which return columns

Comment: no more errors, thanks. But where is the file ? Or I didn't generate it yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Am bit late int he game but here it is

```
self.attribute_names
```

does the job for me.